# reporting:java.util.ConcurrentModificationException java.util.WeakHashMap$HashIterator.next(WeakHashMap.java:165)

Tags: android, exception

I'm getting below error in Android -

```
04-11 12:39:36.890: D/dalvikvm(1854):   GC_CONCURRENT freed 3453K, 75% free     15804K/62215K, paused 2ms+5ms
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     reporting:java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     at java.util.WeakHashMap$HashIterator.next  (WeakHashMap.java:165)
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     at    com.androidquery.callback.BitmapAjaxCallback.callback(BitmapAjaxCallback.java:560)
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     at com.androidquery.callback.BitmapAjaxCallback.callback(BitmapAjaxCallback.java:1)
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     at com.androidquery.callback.AbstractAjaxCallback.callback(AbstractAjaxCallback.java:506)
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     at com.androidquery.callback.AbstractAjaxCallback.afterWork(AbstractAjaxCallback.java:1299)
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     at com.androidquery.callback.AbstractAjaxCallback.run(AbstractAjaxCallback.java:998)
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
04-11 12:39:36.900: W/AQuery(1854):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my code is -

```
if(id==11){
            atp.xt_click("", Constants.CONFIGURATION_INDUSTRIAL_TAB, clicType.action );

//Error is throwing on below if condition, if i'll remove first if condition if(Constants.leftButton.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Industrial")){
//then exception is not throwin

if(Constants.leftButton.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Industrial")){

            if(tileimageLayoutDouble.getVisibility()==0){
                System.out.println("inside onclick of image color of id = "+id);
                View view = (View) e.getLocalState();
                int posDouble = (Integer) view.getTag();
                String styleName = configColrsndMaterialList.get(posDouble).getStyleName();
                String styleGrpName = configColrsndMaterialList.get(posDouble).getStyleGrpName();   
                gangsList = dataBasehandler.getStyleLayouts(styleName, styleGrpName);
                Layout doubleGangLayout = dataBasehandler.getIndustrialStyle(styleName, styleGrpName, Constants.industrialDoubleName);
                intitializeGangsLayout();
                configColrsndMaterialListPath = Constants.imgStoragePath + "/"+ doubleGangLayout.getLayoutImg();   
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BaseActivty) getActivity()).convertBitmap(configColrsndMaterialListPath);
                rangeDetailImageDouble.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  
                saveConfigProduct.setStyleImg(configColrsndMaterialListPath);
                saveConfigProduct.setStyleDesc(doubleGangLayout.getLayoutDesc());
                saveConfigProduct.setStyleName(styleName);
                saveConfigProduct.setStyleGrpName(styleGrpName);        
 }

 }
```

Comment: post BitmapAjaxCallback.java code..from your code we are not getting.

Comment: BitmapAjaxCallback.java class is not in my project, I dont know why or from where BitmapAjaxCallback class thr